# how do I write a program in Visual Basic to make an EXE to save Net Use User data?

Tags: vb.net, exe

I have a computer this is connected to a domain but on the same network as it are non domain computers. I am trying to create an EXE program using VB that saves the user data to access the folders of the non domain computers via file explorer.

I am new to VB so I am likely missing some very obvious steps so I ask for patience.

Lets say I have the main computer `PC1` is on joined to Domain X but on the same network are computers `PCA` `PCB` and `PCC` not joined to the Domain all with username `USER1` and password `Pa$$word`

This is what I have tried but it is not working when the built exe on PC1

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Threading

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Process.Start("CMD", "/c net use \\PCA /user:PCA\USER1 Pa$$word /PERSISTENT:yes")
        Process.Start("CMD", "/c net use \\PCB /user:PCB\USER1 Pa$$word /PERSISTENT:yes")
        Process.Start("CMD", "/c net use \\PCC /user:PCC\USER1 Pa$$word /PERSISTENT:yes")

    End Sub
End Module
```

when debugging it gives

```
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

which I assumed was due to me building the program on a different computer than `PC1`
When trying to run the exe it will flash a black command box for a split second but no text and there is no result of the user info being saved

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are all of these computers running Windows?  Not to specifically ignore your question, but to honest you'd be better of just setting up a Windows scheduled task that runs a batch file with all of the necessary commands in it.  Aside from that, I have a feeling that your net use \\PC....., etc. should be wrapped in double-quotes

Comment: In addition, can you actually ping all of the various computers, from one-another, by using their name?  "The network path was not found" would generally indicate that Windows can't find the computer by the specified name

Comment: All computers are running windows and are ping-able from PC1. 
I am not using VB on PC1 but a different machine not on that network so I do not expect to be able to ping PCA etc. from the computer I am using VB on.

A scheduled task is not an option because on particular users of PC1 are to have access to have access to PCA etc. remotely and access to the EXE would be controlled through AD credentials on the Domain

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but doesn't the path have to be something like \\<ComputerName>\<ShareName>

Comment: if you open a CMD window in PC1 and run the command exactly as you're trying to run it on your code, does it work?

Comment: @Hursey - it is possible to do a net use to just the server name path - ie. \\<ComputerName>.  It essentially establishes a connection and authenticates (much like if you did net use \\<ComputerName>\ipc$) - so that if you then try and connect to other shares it won't need to prompt for authentication.

Comment: @mftt3c - another (probably better) option would be to have the commands added to the domain login script (the specific commands that each user would run can be restricted based on their group membership, for example).  Beyond that, as Josh Part suggests in his comment, have you run the same commands (via command prompt) that you are trying to run from your vb application?  (Specifically, that would mean opening a command prompt window, and then running CMD /C net use ....., etc., and verifying if you get a successful result, or an error

Comment: @Josh part and Craig - Yes running the net use commands exactly as written dose work as expected on PC1 in command prompt

Comment: @mftt3c - If it works normally from the command prompt that might narrow down the problem. We need to figure out what is being done differently. Try compiling to 64 bit if you were previously compiling to 32 bit. Also, when doing it manually, are you doing it in an elevated command prompt?

Comment: I was able to determine the difference between the computer I was building on vs PC1. PC1 does not have .NET installed preventing my EXE from running

Thank you all for the help on this!!

Answer (score 0):

The code as written was correct. the issue was the computer in the environment was not running .NET